# I have a rental apartment that will be vacant for 3-4 months. Should I just unplug or shut off refrigerator?

Tags: refrigerator

I have a rental apartment that will be vacant for 3-4 months. Should I just unplug or shut off refrigerator?

Comment: Clean/wash the inside walls/shelves and let dry.  Water should be turned off and pipes drained for the rental.  Door open might let bugs/mice nest inside, door close might have a musty smell when opening, but should be less if cleaned well first.

Comment: If you don't unplug it, the light will probably use more power in 3-4 months than the refrigerator would if left closed and running.

Comment: A closed up fridge gets extremely disgusting after awhile.  There is lots of trapped water behind the interior skins of your fridge, some trapped as ice, and when you shut off, it raises interior humidity to 100% and mold and mildew go CRAZY.  It's impossible to clean without disassembling the fridge, might as well scrap it at that point.  My rule of thumb is, shut it off with the door physically blocked open for a MONTH to thoroughly dry out.   And you can't use any hokey blocking technique either, because humans are hardwired to close fridge doors on sight.

Answer (score 1):

## Unplugging it is a good idea

It's best to prop the door open a little bit to prevent any smells from developing inside --- and maybe put a small, open box of Baking Soda inside.